# Port Forward For OpenVpn

Tags: linux, networking, centos, openvpn, port-forwarding

I have [setup](http://www.unixmen.com/setup-openvpn-server-client-centos-6-5/) a `OpenVPN` server on CentOS 6, and it starts ok when i

```
/etc/init.d/openvpn start
```

it shows me

```
Starting openvpn:                                          [  OK  ]
```

so far so good, but when i forward port `1194` on my router it appears close to me which indicates(In my opinion) that the server is not listening on the specified port. I have checked it with

```
 netstat -tulpn | grep :1194
```

it shows

```
udp        0      0 192.168.5.33:1194           0.0.0.0:*                               3566/openvpn
```

it doesnot show `Listen` i have tried disabling the firewall but to no avail. What else i can try to get it to work...

P.S. When i enable remote desktop on my windows machine and forward the related port (3389) it appears as open when i check with http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ that is not the case with CentOS (:5901)

Regards...

EDIT

as described in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/470065) i checked that the server is listening to local ip:port that is 192.168.5.33:1194

```
echo -e "\x38\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" |     timeout 10 nc -u 192.168.5.33 1194 | cat -v
```

gives me

```
@M-rM-vM-QM-yM-jM-peF^@^@^@^@^@@M-rM-vM-QM-yM-jM-peF^@^@^@^@^@@M-rM-vM-QM-yM-jM-
```

which means the server is listening but when i replace the local ip with my public one it times out... do i need to start my server on the public ip?

EDIT:2

when i use the `TCP` protocol with `OpenVPN` the status shows its listening

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.5.33:1194           0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      6595/openvpn
```

**EDIT:3**

so the question which arises here is why im seeing `1194` open when i use `TCP` with `openVPN` and closed when i use `UDP` ... in both the cases the `openVPN` starts just fine... do i need to perform some extra steps when i have to use UDP for port forwarding

Comment: Are you forwarding `tcp` and not `udp`?

Comment: i have forwarded both tcp and udp ports

Comment: @jordanm please see the question edit i have confirmed that the server is listening to the local ip:port

Comment: This is not the entire answer to your problem, but I can't comment yet (I guess delete this later). UDP protocol is stateless therefore you won't see any LISTEN in netstat - see other open ports. How do you exactly check the UDP port using public IP?

Comment: @Kuncík please refer to the first edit to check the open-ness of the udp port i just replaced the local ip with the public one and got no response...

Comment: Try to access your public IP from outside your local network. Often port forwarding does not work from within the LAN. Just try to sue the VPN from outside your LAN to check if the server is active or use `echo -e "\x38\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" | socat STDIO UDP:yourserver:openvpn`.